# Magento seo friendly url in custom module

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I would like to create porfolio module, but I need it to be seo friendly, so url should look like:

```
example.com/portfolio/projectid
```

where portfolio - module, so it will be index action
projectid - based on field alias

its easy to create `example.com/portfolio` but how to create controller, or detect what is after?
The same URL hierarchy is in products, so it's category/product

Anybody have idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for item/id. you can change with your requirement.

```
                    $model = Mage::getModel('items/items');

        /*Rewrite */
        $isSystem = 0; // set 0 for custom url as we have created custom for profile extension

        $_itemId = $model->getModuleItemId();//module_item_id field
        $_itemName = $model->getTitle();//title field
        $_itemName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $_itemName));



        // save profile view url rewrite
        $viewIdPath = 'item/id'.'/'.$_itemId;

        $viewRequestPath = 'items/'.$_itemName;
        $viewTargetPath = 'items/index/item/id/'.$_itemId;//controller is itemsController.php, Action is itemAction() 

        $_coreUrlRewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite');
        $_coreUrlRewrite->load($viewIdPath, 'id_path'); // check if item path already saved? If yes, $_coreUrlRewrite will contain existing data.

        $_coreUrlRewrite->setStoreId($_storeId)
        ->setIdPath($viewIdPath)
        ->setRequestPath($viewRequestPath)
        ->setTargetPath($viewTargetPath)
        ->setIsSystem($isSystem)
        ->save();
        if(isset($viewRequestPath)){
            $model->setUrl($viewRequestPath);
            $model->save();
        }

        /*Rewrite End*/
```

You can find more info [here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_rewrites_intro) & [here](http://code-cocktail.in/magento-custom-search-engine-friendly-sef-url/)

Comment: can you add setUrl function?

Comment: "url" is the field that is getting saved in $model->setUrl($viewRequestPath); with the value $viewRequestPath